# Libgdx batch.draw vs sprite.draw

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I load that with TextureAtlas and call TextureAtlas#createSprites("something"). I will get an array of AtlasSprites.I draw these as if whitespace was not stripped using sprite.draw(Batch batch), but also I have to reduce the size of the texture to the size of the world, so I use setSсale, but the texture is not reduced to the size of the world .So I decided to try through batch.draw(Sprite sprite, float x, float y, float width, float height) but it draws like whitespace is stripped. How to draw texture as if whitespace was not stripped and reducing its?

Comment: by "stripped" - you mean white space is showing up transparent when you don't want it too?

Comment: In libgdx TexturePacker have the option stripWhitespaceX, stripWhitespaceY, that's what makes this option: "If true, blank pixels on the left and right edges of input images will be removed. Applications must take special care to draw these regions properly. (For X)". So need to Restore whitespace to display properly running animation example

Answer (score 0):

(*Just FYI*) The `draw` method of `Sprite`, which you were using previously, looks like this:

```
public void draw (Batch batch) {
    batch.draw(texture, getVertices(), 0, SPRITE_SIZE);
}
```

`SPRITE_SIZE` is the number of vertices, and `0` is an "offset", and unfortunately there isn't a similar version of this which uses scaling, at least that I could find.

---

The absolute best way to fix your issue, assuming you have some sprites where you *do* want some transparency, is to recreate your textures with fixed `alpha` values. You can do this in a variety of image-editors. This way your textures are loaded correctly the first time.

An alternative way is to set the `Pixmap.Format` when creating your `Textures` to be `RGB888` rather than `RGBA8888`. The `A` stands for alpha, so you are changing the format of the texture to have no alpha value. (*Just FYI, the `8`'s are the number of bits used for each color channel - Red: 8 bits, Green: 8 bits, Blue: 8 bits*)

However, when using a `TextureAtlas` I am not positive on how to set the texture's output format for your case. I know it takes the `Pixmap.Format` of the `Page` into account, but I am not sure how to apply this to however you have your atlas set up.

There is also a batch setting

```
batch.disableBlending();
```

This will actually cause the batch to run even faster performance-wise. So that's good. However, everything drawn this way will be affected.

Comment: I don't think so. Because i can use sprite.batch method.The only problem that arises is the size of the texture. Initially, I tried but the texture will sprite.setsize  become smaller each time the drawing, so that I will have to draw upon to restore the original size but I do not like this option because This will affect the performance. I think I will resize using sprite.setSсale but the texture remains the same size.